# HTML Datalist not getting populated

Tags: html, html-datalist

This is the sample html document. The datalist tag is added for the fave input text box. But it does show up. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <meta name="description" content="A simple example"/>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="WorkingWithFormsChapter.html" target="_blank">
        <label for="fave">Enther your favourite fruit</label>
        <input name="fave" autofocus="true" list="fruitslist"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="name">Enter your name</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Your name please" />
        <button>Submit Vote</button>
    </form>
    <datalist id="fruitslist">
        <option value="Tasty Apples">Apples</option>
        <option value="Juicy Oranges">Juicy Oranges</option>
    </datalist>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is working for me see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PNKTJ/

Comment: Apparently it works with google chrome, But i was using Komodo edit tool and it is failing to display the datalists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works; the [support for it in some browsers at the moment is not good](http://caniuse.com/datalist) however.

Comment: Partly due to lack of support in old browsers, partly due to differences in implementations, you should normally use `option` elements without content (just with `value` attribute). Old browsers (e.g. IE 9) will display the content visibly, which might be rather confusing.